# App crashes using Facebook Login SDK when I go to the home screen

Tags: ios, swift, fbsdk, fbsdkloginkit

I originally downloaded the FBSDK's version 4.10 and integrated them into my application by placing them in the frameworks folder. Realizing that these would not get updated over time, I removed them completely and tried to add them as pods to my project. The pods installed successfully, I have imported them correctly in my bridging header file, and there were no other issues. The pods update installed version 4.11 which has caused me some headache.

I am using the FBSDKLoginKit to log a user into their account and retrieve information from that. I am able to get back a dictionary with the users information just fine. I then pass this information to the next ViewController with a segue. At any point after this, if I press the home button on my iPhone or simulator, the app will crash. The error I get is

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException',
reason: '*** -[__NSPlaceholderDictionary initWithObjects:forKeys:count:]: 
attempt to insert nil object from objects[3]'
```

This exception also occurs if I let the user log in through facebook, segue to the new view controller, unwind to the previous view controller, and then attempt to log in again. I have attempted to log the user out once retrieving their pertinent information on the second screen, but the error still persists.

I have seen a similar question asked where the "solution" was that the FBSDKLoginKit writes the retrieved dictionary to a variable and if the dictionary it has retrieved back has nil values, it throws this error.

Is there anything I can do to catch this before it happens? Has anyone found a work around?

Here is my output from the simulator when I press home:

```
*** First throw call stack:
(
0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000106f03d85 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010643edeb objc_exception_throw + 48
2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000106e0023e -[__NSPlaceholderDictionary initWithObjects:forKeys:count:] + 318
3   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000106e125bb +[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:forKeys:count:] + 59
4   APPNAME                               0x0000000101607a1e -[FBSDKTimeSpentData instanceSuspend] + 622
5   APPNAME                                0x000000010160766b +[FBSDKTimeSpentData suspend] + 59
6   APPNAME                                0x00000001015b5986 -[FBSDKAppEvents applicationMovingFromActiveStateOrTerminating] + 262
7   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000106ecdc8c __CFNOTIFICATIONCENTER_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER__ + 12
8   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000106ecd9cb _CFXRegistrationPost + 427
9   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000106ecd732 ___CFXNotificationPost_block_invoke + 50
10  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000106f161e2 -[_CFXNotificationRegistrar find:object:observer:enumerator:] + 1986
11  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000106dc5679 _CFXNotificationPost + 633
12  Foundation                          0x000000010372ccd9 -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 66
13  UIKit                               0x0000000104a685ad -[UIApplication _deactivateForReason:notify:] + 629
14  UIKit                               0x0000000104a6f1f1 __61-[UIApplication _sceneSettingsPreLifecycleEventDiffInspector]_block_invoke + 104
15  FrontBoardServices                  0x0000000108f88d6c __52-[FBSSettingsDiffInspector inspectDiff:withContext:]_block_invoke27 + 213
16  Foundation                          0x000000010377d5bb __NSIndexSetEnumerate + 1016
17  BaseBoard                           0x000000010901ba8c -[BSSettingsDiff inspectChangesWithBlock:] + 116
18  FrontBoardServices                  0x0000000108f83e4a -[FBSSettingsDiff inspectOtherChangesWithBlock:] + 92
19  FrontBoardServices                  0x0000000108f88b2f -[FBSSettingsDiffInspector inspectDiff:withContext:] + 317
20  UIKit                               0x0000000104a70880 __70-[UIApplication scene:didUpdateWithDiff:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke + 127
21  UIKit                               0x0000000104a7052d -[UIApplication scene:didUpdateWithDiff:transitionContext:completion:] + 843
22  FrontBoardServices                  0x0000000108f978c8 __FBSSERIALQUEUE_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 24
23  FrontBoardServices                  0x0000000108f97741 -[FBSSerialQueue _performNext] + 178
24  FrontBoardServices                  0x0000000108f97aca -[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] + 45
25  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000106e29301 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
26  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000106e1f22c __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 556
27  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000106e1e6e3 __CFRunLoopRun + 867
28  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000106e1e0f8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 488
29  GraphicsServices                    0x0000000108ae7ad2 GSEventRunModal + 161
30  UIKit                               0x0000000104a72f09 UIApplicationMain + 171
31  APPNAME                                0x00000001013a26d2 main + 114
32  libdyld.dylib                       0x0000000107b0d92d start + 1
33  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
```

)
    libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Running my code step by step I find that the error occurs during the method:

```
fbLoginManager.logInWithReadPermissions(permissionsNeeded, fromViewController: self) { (result, error) -> Void in 
//crashes before it enters this block    
//my code here
}
```

It crashes before I can even check the error value. I will attempt to check the values by stepping into the fbsdk methods and update

[image: fbsdk browser permissions login]

As soon as I press OK on this screen for the second time it crashes. How can I debug this? The action isn't in my app, its in the browser so I'm not sure where to go from here..

Comment: check your response and dictionary creation, looks like you are attempting to insert nil

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have came across this issues recently, and i solved it by adding this piece of code in **Appdelegate.m**.

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {    

    [FBSDKAppEvents activateApp];
}
```

For Swift 3 version:

```
func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {

    FBSDKAppEvents.activateApp()
}
```

Comment: This didn't help. The app crashes here all the times when I come back to iOS app from the Facebook app for login.

Comment: App crashes everytime coming back from Facebook. Even tried with latest SDK 4.33

Answer (score 1):

Update to 4.12, it fixes the issue according to their release notes:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/change-log-4.x/

The part that says:

Fixed

- **Fixed cases where AppEvents could crash because of missing session id.**
- Fixed bug in some cases where access token expiration date was the refresh date.

Answer (score 0):

Although this is not necessarily a comprehensive solution, I have exhausted my debugging methods. I have removed the FBSDK's from my podfile, run pod update to remove them from the project, and reinstalled the version 4.10 FBSDK's in my frameworks folder. I will update this question after trying again when facebook releases an updated version of the FBSDK's.